# FabricJS with DrawingMode in Zoomed parent do not work correctly

Tags: fabricjs

I have an issue when I zoom In/Out the parent component of a FabricJS Canvas in DrawingMode
I have the following component:

```
<div id="board">
    <canvas id="whiteboard"></canvas>
    <div class="pawn"></div>
</div>
```

Default behavior is OK, when I zoom the #board with css zoom property everything scale properly

BUT the hand drawing no longer works because the x,y mouse coordinated might use client X/Y without the zoom level of the parent. Even if I create a new fabric.Canvas after zoom.

Is there a work around ?

Comment: I think a better solution will be to use the zoom functionality from fabricjs http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5.

Comment: @MariusTurcu I can't because I don't want to but everything in a Canvas. It's only a layer to draw things on top of other content